# JSONObject is not a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Below is the JSON string response which I receive. I am parsing it using JSON.

```
String jsonString = "{\"a\":{\"b\":{\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":\"00\",\"f\":\"A\",\"g\":\"2\",\"h\":\"24\",\"i\":[{\"TypeFile\":\"232\",\"Request\":\"ere\",\"Thle\":\"999999\"},{\"TypeFile\":\"0720\",\"Request\":\"Y\",\"Thle\":\"999999\"}]},\"asd\":\"http://google.com/Itest\"}}";
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(jsonString );
System.out.println(obj1);
//JSONObject obj = obj1.getJSONObject("a").getJSONObject("b");
//System.out.println(obj.getJSONArray("c"));
JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject("a");
System.out.println(obj2);
JSONObject obj3 = obj2.getJSONObject("b");
System.out.println(obj3.get("e"));
System.out.println(obj2.get("asd"));
System.out.println(obj3 instanceof JSONObject);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{"errorMsg": "JSONObject['b'] is not a JSONObject."}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: That is not an error related to the code you've posted. Where do you see it?

Comment: where is errorMsg part in your JSON?

Comment: The code works good in java..I m seeing the error in MCP Logs/genesys.. So the code is good right ? As i dont have reputation i could not add the tag..

Comment: I am having an array inside JSON object.. WHhether any way to parse other than i done please anybody share..Thanks for ur help in advance..!!

Comment: did you **analyze** `obj2.getJSONObject("b");` via debugger? this may help to identify the problem

Comment: @Ben :Thanks for response..I am not seeing obj3 in variables under debugging..But i can see JSONobject for obj1 and obj2.,What still missing?

Comment: assuming you are using an standard IDE, what do you see (in debug-mode, breakpoint at obj3 line), when you analyze `obj2`with any kind of Object-Explorer?

Comment: I tried to debug..WHen  i click step into in debug i could see JSONObject for obj3 in variables...

Comment: I would guess that you have two JSONObject classes defined in different packages.  It's expecting one but you're giving it another.  Like org.json.JSONObject and net.minidev.JSONObject, for instance.

Comment: @Carl : Not like that.

Comment: `... I could see JSONObject for obj3 in variables` so it seems that at some point there is an exception thrown on your side. Have you followed the path till something unexpected happened? What version of java and `org.json` are you using? any other dependencies available? Do you use maven or gradle for dependency management?

Answer (score 0):

as a suggestion, you can try this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = obj1.getJSONArray("b"); //try to get an JSONArray
String s = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("e"); //then you can try this...
```